# Apache airflow DAG task status - web api

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is there a way to get the current status of the most recent DAG run though Airflow api? I've tried the experimental api with this:

```
/api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/tasks/<TASK_ID>
```

But that only gives information about the task, not the status of each run. Basically I need to be able to get the result of the most recent run of the task - success, fail, queued etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a task that will check the airflow database on `task_instance.state`. You can have a task or a separate DAG that will look for the dag status on database you wanted to check on a specific execution date.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same need using Airflow 1.10.12 and solved it using this service:

```
GET /api/experimental/dags/<string:dag_id>/dag_runs/<string:execution_date>
```

It will return a JSON in this format:

```
{"state":"running"}
```